# throw new TypeError("expecting a function but got " + util.classString(fn)); TypeError: expecting a function but got [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, bluebird, node-promisify

While running `node app.js` the Express server is connecting properly and the MongoDB is connecting correctly, but I am facing a problem in the node module as mentioned above.

The complete log is pasted below:

```
        throw new TypeError("expecting a function but got " + util.classString(fn));
        ^

TypeError: expecting a function but got [object Undefined]
    at Function.Promise.promisify (D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promisify.js:270:15)
    at D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:155:56
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at MongoStore.setCollection (D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:154:67)    
    at MongoStore.handleNewConnectionAsync (D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:120:18)
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:91:72) 
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
    at NativeConnection.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:647:8)
    at _setClient (D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:895:8)
    at D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:797:7
    at D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:423:9
    at D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:130:17 at connectCallback (D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:29:9)
    at D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:80:9    
    at Object.callback (D:\Project\DD-NODEJS\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:230:17)
```

To view Index.js [Click Here](https://codeshare.io/zyYVAW)
To view App.js [Click Here](https://codeshare.io/6pLykQ)

Comment: Please give a [mre]. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: Please add the code snippet from ```index.js``` file as well.

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad I have added the link, please review it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi was facing a similar issue while connecting MongoDB session in nodejs.

Steps to fix:

1. update the mongoose and connect-mongo package.
2. update the require statement. Remove (session) from it.
   const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
3. update the code

   ```
   app.use(
    session({
    secret: 'story book',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: YourDatabaseURL
     })
    })
   );
   ```